# How does the image quality compare between these lenses?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, zoom

Want to buy a zoom lens for Nikon D5100 [now only have  the kit lens 18-55mm].
I've selected these options

- AF Zoom-NIKK0R 70-300mm f/4-5.6G
- Tamron AF 70-300mm F/4-5.6 Di LD Macro
- Sigma 70-300mm F/4-5.6 DG Macro
- AF-S DX Zoom-NIKKOR 55-200mm f/4-5.6G ED

Will there be any visible difference in the image quality because of the brands *or* will all of them deliver similar quality just because they are inexpensive?

Comment: See also - [Where can I find reviews of lenses?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1520/where-can-i-find-reviews-of-lenses)

Comment: Also http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/21100/looking-for-a-good-cheap-entry-level-telephoto-lens-for-nikon-d5100/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Nikkor 70-300mm F/4.5-5.6G will deliver the most sharpness and least vignetting.** It stands out most from the other lenses and exhibits less optical distortion.

The Sigma 70-300mm and Tamron 70-300mm are pretty soft and similar in performance except that Tamron vignettes less. While the Nikkor 55-200mm F/4-5.5G is sharper than both third-party models, it vignettes terribly so near the middle of its range. Optical distortion is not so high with these models with the Tamron doing slightly better and the Sigma worse.